# MIDL2398 error building with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com

I'm seeing a MIDL2398 error every time I try to compile a Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2010) project which uses COM. This project builds perfectly fine on my Windows 7 developer machine and on a Windows Server 2008 build machine, but not on a Windows Server 2012 build machine.

I found this web site about the various MIDL compiler errors: http://blog.yezhucn.com/midl/compiler_errors.htm

But, I tried it's suggestion for MIDL2398, I verified that "midlc.exe" was in the same directory as "midl.exe" and that both were the same version (both are file version: 7.0.555.1 product version: 6.1.7600.16385, from the Windows SDK v7.1).

I'm guessing it has something to do with Windows Server 2012, but I don't know.

Has anyone been able to get the Windows SDK v7.1 MIDL compiler to work on Windows Server 2012? Or, does anyone know of what else might be causing MIDL2398?

Comment: From the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt, type "where midl*.exe" and verify that only these two files are found.  SysInternals' ProcMon is another way to verify that the correct EXE files are used.

Comment: I did that inside the pre-build event for the project I was building, and that command gave me the path to the Windows SDK v7.1 midl EXEs, which is what I expected. I also changed the project settings to try using the Windows SDK v7.0A (included with Visual Studio 2010), the where command correctly reported the path to the v7.0A version of the midl EXEs, but I still get the same midl error regardless of whether I compile against Windows SDK v7.0A or v7.1. A co-worker, on the same Windows 2012 virtual machine, tried compiling with version 8 of the Windows SDK and that also failed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I installed the SysInternals suite ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals ) on the build server and then used Process Monitor (procmon) to see what MIDL.exe was trying and failing to do.

In my case, it turned out that there was a file at the root of the C: drive named "Program", so the path to this file was "C:\Program". I don't know what or why, but MIDL.exe was doing something with this file. I renamed the file to "Program--MW", and the MIDL2398 error went away.

If anyone else runs into the MIDL2398 error, I recommend that you also use SysInternals' Process Monitor, add a filter for Process Name -- Contains -- midl, run your compiler and examine the Process Monitor log for errors and strange behavior. It worked for me!

Comment: I had the exact same issue, thanks! No idea how that file named program got there

Comment: I see that you have [reported the bug on connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771055/midl-compiler-fails-with-midl2398-error-when-a-file-exists-at-c-program). Although the report was closed in 2012, I can confirm that the problem still exists in Visual Studio 2013 update 5. In my case the file `C:\Program` was created by one of our internal utilities that was unable to handle paths with spaces - it truncated `C:\Program Files\...´ to simply ´C:\Program´ and then happily wrote stuff into that file.

Comment: Hello from 2017! Visual Studio 2015 still got this problem, also solution helps!

Comment: Hello from 2020 - and VS 2019, somehow got the same Program file (0 byte) and deleting it solved it.

Answer (score 2):

On VS2012, the midl error was caused by com0com installer which created the file Program under the C drive. This is messing with the MIDL as mentioned earlier.

The file C:\Program had the following. Just renaming this file to something else, Ex: C:__Program makes Midl happy.

```
DIALOG: {
SetupOpenInfFile(C:\WINDOWS\system32\com0com.inf) on line 0
ERROR: 2 - The system cannot find the file specified.


} ...
```

Comment: So great ! rename file c:\Program, so safe my life !

Answer (score 0):

The other answers is generally true. Specifically, on my case though, the presence of that *damn* file was further down in the folder hierarchy, which causes **midl** to go haywire. I used a **Cygwin** shell in Windows environment and below is a complete  fully replayable screen cast video of the problem and then the solution.

https://asciinema.org/a/W2wEnv4y8nWHNWl5P3NIw8GnF